# How to create non-read-only directories from Java in Windows

Tags: java, windows, file-permissions, mkdir, mkdirs

I'm creating directories using `myFileObject.mkdirs()`. In Windows, every directory that gets created is marked as read-only. Although I can (oddly) still write to the directory, it creates aggravation when it comes to deleting things.

Is there some system property or something I can set so that the default permission on new directories is read-write? (I've searched on SO and the web and haven't found anything besides other people complaining about the same thing.) It's a pain to have to call setWritable for a directory tree. (If it makes a difference, I'm using J2SE 1.6.0_23 on Windows 7.)

Comment: Java creates directories/files with the default permissions specified by the OS.  If the permissions are not correct I suggest you change it at the OS level.

Comment: @Peter, I don't think he's talking about permissions but about the read-only attribute.

Comment: @Ted, I can't reproduce this.  Can you provide more information, maybe some simple code exhibiting the problem?  Have you tried the latest update, 6u29?

Comment: @Ted, regarding Psycho's answer, are you sure the directories are really being set read-only?  Have you checked using the attrib command?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, I thought the read-only attribute had something to do with the permissions of the directory.

Comment: @Peter, no, the read-only attribute predates file permissions.  It's not often used nowadays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand there is no way to do this from java it's not java problem. For example let's create folder from cmd and you will see the same problem ([ms error](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;326549)). 
cmd 
md sampleDir
attrib -r sampleDir

Attribute will stay as it was on creation step. But If you are seeing a blue square for "Read only", then it is not marked as read-only by default. The blue just stands for a undetermined blank state. Only if it had a check mark in the box would it be marked as read-only.

If you can create .bat file that will create this job you could call it from Java:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c run.bat");
```

It's not true way but if it's work - it's better then anything.

Comment: The article you link to describes a limitation in the GUI, it doesn't describe an error and certainly doesn't explain why Ted's directories are getting marked read-only (or having odd permissions assigned to them as the case may be).

Comment: Oh, I think I see - are you saying that Ted may be mistakenly thinking the directories are read-only because the GUI is misleading?

Comment: Yep, as I understand, this attribute(default attribute for created files) doesn't says that this folder is read only. But some limitations are could be (required google :) ) but it's not question for java.

Comment: Windows Explorer shows a green square. I didn't realize that was an "undetermined blank state". The reason I looked at it in the first place was that when I tried to delete the directory tree that my program created, a pop-up claimed that I needed administrator privilege. Seeing the green square, I thought that was the problem. But I haven't been able to reproduce the privilege problem since then. So I think this is the right answer--I was misinterpreting what I was seeing. Thanks to everyone for the quick feedback.